# Listview is updating upon clicking back button in fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

Here I'm trying to get data from URL and displaying in Listview in Fragment A. Its working perfectly. But Upon clicking on items of listview it navigates to next fragment B. When I navigate to Fragment A from Fragment B using back button then Listview Items updates again. If there are 3 items in listview and user navigates from B to A 2 times, then then total no. of items in Listview will be 9. Please help in stop this redundancy

```
public class EnglishFragment extends Fragment {


 private List<DataItem> dataFeed= new ArrayList<DataItem>();
    ListView listView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final ArrayAdapter<DataItem> adapter = new EnglishFragment.Adapter();

        View view;

        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_topic2,container,false);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        // JsonObjectRequest myReq= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,

        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, **URL**, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray dataArray = response.getJSONArray("topic");
                            Log.i("Temp",""+dataArray.length());
                            for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length();i++) {
                                JSONObject temp = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.i("Temp",temp.toString());


                                String first_name = temp.getString("name");
                                String last_name = temp.getString("details");
                                String image_path =temp.getString("img_path");;
                                String chapter_path = temp.getString("url");
                                Log.i("Image",temp.getString("url"));

                                dataFeed.add(new DataItem(first_name,last_name," "," ", image_path,chapter_path));
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy( new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

        listView.setAdapter( adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                DataItem currentItem = dataFeed.get(position);

                Log.v("position", currentItem.getImageURL());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), currentItem.getChapterURL(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
                mainActivity.getChapterList(currentItem.getChapterURL());

            }

        });


       return view;
    }
    private class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataItem> {

        public Adapter() {
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.data_items,dataFeed);
        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.data_items,null,false);

            }

            DataItem currentItem = dataFeed.get(position);
            TextView heading = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.subject_name);
            TextView desc = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.subject_details);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.leftIcon);


            heading.setText(currentItem.getNewsHeading() + " ");
            desc.setText(Html.fromHtml(currentItem.getNewsDesc()));
            imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageId());
            Picasso.get().load(currentItem.getImageURL()).into(imageView);

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

**Code of MainActivity.getChapterURL()**

```
public void getChapterList(String ChapterURL ){

    FragmentManager fragmentManager  = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ChapterListFragment chapterListFragment = new ChapterListFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("url",ChapterURL);
        chapterListFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container,chapterListFragment).addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();



}
```

Comment: Are you adding items to the list in a method that gets called every time the `Fragment` starts? If yes, then they get added a lot of times during navigation. Have a look at [the lifecycle of a `Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clear the dataFeed list before adding new data...
    dataFeed.clear()

Comment: It worked! Its a great help. I highly appreciate your help mate!